# ES6. Клонирование объектов через спред оператор

Tags: ecmascript-6

Есть ли разница в способах клонирования объектов с использованием спред оператора?

```
const a = { s:1, d:2 };
// этим способом
const {...b} = a;
// и этим способом
const c = {...a};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по тестам при необходимости клонирования объекта "как есть" никакой разницы нет.

Однако если нужно убрать, добавить или изменить что-то в результирующем объекте тогда разница есть.

- *Если нужно клонировать целевой объект частично тогда наш выбор первый вариант:*

  ```
  const first = { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 };
  const { a, ...second } = first;
  console.log(second); // => { b:2, c:3, d:4 };
  ```
- *Если нужно клонировать целевой объект и добавить или изменить какие-то поля тогда наш выбор второй вариант:*

  Добавить:

  ```
  const first = { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 };
  const second = { ...first, e: 5};
  console.log(second); // => { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 };
  ```

  Изменить:

  ```
  const first = { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 };
  const second = { ...first, d: 5};
  console.log(second); // => { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:5 };
  ```